# solving equation in terms of $w_1$ and $w_2$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics, mathematical-physics

I have a a physics problem involves the following equation 
$$\tan(\alpha) = \frac{(w_1 + w_2)^{1/2}}{w_3}$$ from a certain set of equations that I use I derive the following equation:

$$\frac{\mathrm{d}w_1}{\mathrm{d}t}w_1 + \frac{\mathrm{d}w_2}{\mathrm{d}t}w_2 + \frac{c}{I}(w_1^2 + w_2^2) = 0$$

Now I need to find $w_1^2 + w_2^2$ in terms of time that is how they change with respect to time in order to derive the relation that I want.

Comment: If you let $Y = w_1^2 + w_2^2$ then your equation reads $\frac{dY}{dt} + \frac{2c}{I} Y = 0$. This should be a well-known differential equation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since
$$
\frac{dw_1}{dt}w_1+\frac{dw_2}{dt}w_2=\frac12\frac{d}{dt}(w_1^2+w_2^2),
$$
your differential equation is equivalent to:
$$\tag{1}
\frac{du}{dt}=\alpha u,
$$
with
$$
u=w_1^2+w_2^2,\quad \alpha=-2\frac{c}{I}.
$$
Solving (1) we get:
$$
w_1^2(t)+w_2^2(t)=\beta\exp\left(-2\frac{ct}{I}\right),
$$
where
$$
\beta=w_1^2(0)+w_2^2(0).
$$

Comment: How did you get your $\beta$?